# Node.js Rethrow non-MySQL errors

Tags: node.js

```
var connection = mysql.createPool({
  host     : '***********',
  user     : '**',
  password : '****',
  database : '***',
});

connection.query('SELECT summa FROM bet WHERE id_vk = "'+id_vk2+'"',function(err41,sum){
  if (err41) {
    console.log("Oops... Something went wrong");
  } else {
    summq2 = (sum[0]);
    summq = summq2.summa; // line 140
  }
});
```

**Node.js выдает ошибку:**

> throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'summa' of undefined
>       at Query. (/var/log/installer/eroors.js:140:31)
>       at Query. (/var/log/installer/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:502:10)
>       at Query._callback (/var/log/installer/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:468:16)
>       at Query.Sequence.end (/var/log/installer/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
>       at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/var/log/installer/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:139:8)
>       at Query.EofPacket (/var/log/installer/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:123:8)
>       at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/log/installer/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:278:23)
>       at Parser.write (/var/log/installer/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
>       at Protocol.write (/var/log/installer/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
>       at Socket. (/var/log/installer/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:91:28)

Comment: Потому что переменная `summq2` равна `undefined `.

Comment: Так сервер работает часов 6 и всё норм,потом бац  и undefined

Comment: Время работы сервера не важно. Если у вас нет записи в таблице `bet`  с пришедшим`id_vk2`, то будет такая ошибка.

Comment: У меня эта таблица полностью стирается каждые 2 минуты,потом заполняется пользователями

Comment: Ну вот, в какой-то момент времени, когда таблица пустая, делается этот запрос и выкидывает ошибку. Поправить можно так `summq = summq2?summq2.summa:0;`.

Comment: спасибо помогло